# Is it necessary to use ajax in the following code?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have two jsp say test1.jsp and test2.jsp. My program flow is as follows. I want to know if ajax is necessary here? I need to retrieve the data in a textbox of test1.jsp. But the ajax call is made from a different page. I want the controller response in my test1.jsp. How can I do it?

**test1.jsp**

```
<input type="text" id="testid"/>
<input type="button" onclick="fnopenwindow()"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="abc.js"></script>
```

**test2.jsp**

```
<script>
function fnsample(){
   //some code
    var l1=/*some value*/
    var l2=/*some value*/
    fnPassData(l1,l2);
}
</script>
<div id="map"> </div>
<body onload="fnsample()" >
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="abc.js"></script>
```

**abc.js**

```
function fnopenwindow(){
window.open("test2.jsp","name","width=600px;height=400px");
}

function fnPassData(l1,l2){
    var url="home/test";
    var data= 'var1=' + l1 + '&var2=' + l2;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:url,
        data:data,
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(responseJSON){
            alert(responseJSON);
        }
    });
}
```

controller class

```
@Path("test")
public ModelandView gettest(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelandView responseView = new ModelandView(new JsonView());
    //some code here
    if (somecondition) {
        responseView.addObject("data", dataID);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not present");
    }
    return responseView;
}
```

**Edited::**

I am sending some data from my script to controller through ajax and getting back the response to the same jsp ie. test2.jsp. But I want to send the response of controller to a different jsp ie. test1.jsp. As I am not refreshing any part of test2.jsp Is there any other way to send data from test2.jsp to the controller and then call an ajax from my test1.jsp and get the data from the same controller?

Comment: Yes sir i am using spring

Answer (score 0):

Your doubt absolutely making sense and there is no need to make an AJAX call, since the call is being made in `onload()`

Normally, AJAX calls useful/should written once document is ready and when on some action by the client/user.

Comment: yeah right But how do i send data from my code to controller without ajax and get back the data to my test1.jsp?

Comment: @Vidya , then go for AJAX to reload only Some part of code without reloading whole page.

Comment: 1)Write a servlet  2)get the textbox value  there 3)set the value to a attribute 4)Dispatch your jsp from servlet 5)get attribute value in jsp.

Comment: Sir i have edited my question. And posted the actual problem. I request uu to read it again.

Comment: @Vidya Sorry, but I'm confused on your edit part. If you want to use the same controller, pass a param in your ajax call and check that in your controller.

Comment: I need to send the response data to some other jsp page I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From your edit in the question ,

> No . You cant do in that way

First of all understand the purpose of ajax,

***Ajax is meant for loading a part of page , without refreshing the entire page***

So in your design , you can either the return the response to the same jsp page using the ajax call

or either forward the response to the someother page on the page post without ajax.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: How do I pass response to someother page without ajax? And more basically I need to change the part of page which is already loaded.

Comment: You can post the contents of the page using a form , once you post the form you can get all its attributes . Else you can send the attributes with the url

Comment: So first i do an ajax call get the response and in the success function I do window.location="url"?+responsedata;  and receive as request .getAttribute in my receiving jsp? And then I send it to required field.

Comment: @vidya use of doing an ajax call is to show the result in the same page , but in your case you are sending the respose to another page . so ajax use fails

Comment: let continue it in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56930/san-created-for-jdbc)

Comment: I submitted the form to the controller from my second.jsp . Now not knowing how to access it in first jsp
In my controller evrything is working fine and getting required results. But i want to send those results to my first jsp.